# Subscribing event of Dynamically Loaded User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, user-controls

I have two usercontrols. One is loaded statically another dynamically.

In the aspx page I can write  as follows for static user control.

```
 ProgramAddSchedule.onNewProgram += new AddProgram.OnNewProgramClick(onNewProgram_btnHandler);
```

But dynamically loaded control’s event I am not able to get

```
 Control myUserControl = (Control)Page.LoadControl("~/View/EditScheduleProgram.ascx");
```

How do I get the event of the dynamically loaded control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the name of the type follows the name of the file, you can strongly-type it to that type, such that,

```
var myUserControl = Page.LoadControl("~/View/EditScheduleProgram.ascx") as EditScheduleProgram;
```

Then you have access to any custom (or specific) events exposed by that type but not by `Control`, so,

```
myUserControl.MyEvent += MyEventHandler;
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast to your Control Type

```
 YourControlType myUserControl =(YourControlType)Page.LoadControl("~/View/EditScheduleProgram.ascx");
 myUserControl.onNewProgram += new AddProgram.OnNewProgramClick(onNewProgram_btnHandler);
```